# How to Scale A JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, scaling

I am going to make a Tetris clone. In order to make it look more authentic, I want to draw it in a 160x144 area, but scale it to a 640x576 (scaled 4x), so that every pixel looks like 4 pixels. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using simple, straightforward Graphics and Graphics2D objects, then drawing a simple square may suffice.

```
gfx.fillRect(x, y, width, height)
```

I'll write a method to do this for myself to make things easier, i.e.

```
final static int SIZE = 4;

...

public void drawBigPixel(int x, int y, Color col) {
   gfx.setColor(col);
   gfx.fillRect(x * SIZE, y * SIZE, SIZE, SIZE);
}
```